# Parse Error MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

i have a problem with my project MVC3. I have update NuGet Package Manager for the versions 2.8.50313.31 and Install-Package Bootstrap in Console. After my project upgrading in MVC 5.1.

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

After i have an error in my project which was not earlier.

**The using block is missing a closing "}" character.
Make sure you have a matching "}" character 
for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.**

```
String 43: </script>
String 44: 
String 45: @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
String 46: @Html.ValidationSummary()
String 47:
```

Thanks in advance for all your help

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
String 46: @Html.ValidationSummary()
}`

needs a closing tag

Comment: I tried a lot of options - did not help. I think the another problem

Comment: Generate a new view and see what is different. Arijt is right, you miss a closing bracket just like the error says.

Comment: @RalphJansen thats is what the error is clearly mentioned, if would be better the SAD put some more view code rather than assemble code

Comment: code same how in project MVC 3 , but in MVC 5 an this error

Comment: Can you try to remove the dependentassembly: `assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor"`. I don't see that in my MVC 5.x application. I think it is an old syntax. It must be a razor issue then. Try to create a new MVC 5 application and check the web.config in the root of your application and the web.config in your views folder.

Comment: "Generate a new view and see what is different". thank's you are right !!!

Comment: Create a new Project and check the difference in webconfig. Because its clearly explains parser issue missing }. "Code never lies but Comments Some time do" this is my logic

Comment: I solved the problem. The error was in the comment markup: "<! ---->"